# How to remove the li element on click from the list in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

```
    var ListItem = require('./listItem');

    var App = React.createClass({ 
    getInitialState : function(){
        return{
        items : []
    }
    },

    deleteElement: function(){
    },

    addElement : function(){
        this.state.items.push(<ListItem />);
        this.forceUpdate();
    },

    render : function(){
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>{this.state.items.map(function(item,i){return (
                <li>
                    <p onClick='this.deleteElement'>(-)</p>
                    {item}
                </li>
            )})}</ul>
            <p onClick='this.addElement'>(+)</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
    });
```

> Currently I can add `li` elements to the array using `addElement function`.But can't figure out how to remove the particular `li` element from the `ul` list on clicking the `deleteElement function`.I tried using `splice()` but didn't work.I am new to reactjs.So don't know how to remove the li elements on click in the react way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code there are several mistakes

1. don't use `this.forceUpdate();`, instead you should use `setState`
2. to `onClick` you should pass reference to function not string `'this.addElement'`

Now consider how you can delete elemet from list., you need pass to `deleteElement` index `this.deleteElement.bind(this, i)` and remove element by index from `items` array, and then set new state

```
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState : function(){
    return {
      items : []
    }
  },

  deleteElement: function(index) {
    this.setState({
        items: this.state.items.filter(function (e, i) {
        return i !== index;
      })
    });
  },

  addElement: function() {   
    this.setState({
        items: this.state.items.concat(<ListItem time={ +new Date() } />)
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    var list = this.state.items.map(function(item, i) {
      return <li key={ i }>
        <p onClick={ this.deleteElement.bind(this, i) }>(-)</p>
        <span>{ item }</span>
      </li>
    }, this);

    return <div>
      <ul>{ list }</ul>
      <p onClick={ this.addElement }>(+)</p>
    </div>
  }
});
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/31010/)

Comment: Your fiddle works perfectly.Exactly What I needed.But my code is same as your's in the fiddle.But When I click (-) always the last element in the list get's deleted.

Comment: @Vishwasraj Could you create fiddle with your code? I'll check it

Comment: I have added the fiddle link.

Comment: @Vishwasraj it's works, you are using `i` - but after set new state triggers re-render and you see new indexes for array. You need use uniq `id`;

Answer (score 0):

In your map, when setting up the deleteElement callback, pass in the index of the current item.

```
<p onClick={ function () { this.deleteElement(i) }  }>(-)</p>
```

Then you can build a new array by slicing it and excluding the current index.

```
deleteElement: function(index){
  var items = this.state.items;
  var leftSide = items.slice(0, index);
  var rightSide = items.slice(index + 1, items.length);
  this.setState({ items: leftSide.concat(rightSide) });
}
```

`slice` is preferred to `splice` because `slice` will not mutate an existing array. Here we build a new array and avoid any mutations.

If you're using ES6 this can be reduced slightly:

```
<p onClick={() => this.deleteElement(i) }>(-)</p>

deleteElement: (index) => {
  var items = this.state.items;
  var leftSide = items.slice(0, index);
  var rightSide = items.slice(index + 1, items.length);
  this.setState({ items: [...leftSide, ...rightSide] });
}
```

Once downside to be aware of when doing this, the function surrounding `deleteElement` in your JSX will be re-created on every `render`. This creates more work for the garbage collector because there will be a bunch of unused function pointers in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what would I do...

```
remove(idx) {
  return (event) => {
    // Concatening original items array returns new array - this is important!
    const items = this.state.items.concat();
    items.splice(idx, 1);
    this.setState({ items });
  }
},

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      ...
      <ul>
        { this.state.items.map((item, i) => <Item key={i} remove={this.remove(i)} text={item}  />) }
      </ul>
      ...
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here, you are passing index of item you would like to remove. Of course, calling function would be no good in render - it would remove all items on render (actually, you should not change state in render method). Instead, you return function that will be executed on click.

Item component could look similar to this:

```
const Item = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <li>
        { this.props.text }
        <span onClick={this.props.remove}>&times;</span>
      </li>
    );
  }
});
```

Working fiddle here... https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/31009/

Comment: `{ this.remove(i) }` will trigger the remove function before the click, won't it? The handler needs to be passed a function.

Comment: No, it won't. Please, read carefully. `this.remove(i)` returns function, which is invoked on click, indeed. Take a look at Fiddle example, play with it :)

Comment: I see. I hadn't noticed that `remove` was a higher-order function. Thanks for clarifying!